# improve javascript prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm using a classical javascript prototypal inheritance, like this:

```
function Foo() {}   
Naknek.prototype = {
//Do something
};
var Foo = window.Foo = new Foo();
```

I want to know how I can improve this and why I can't use this model:

```
var Foo = window.Foo = new function() {
};
Foo.prototype = {
//Do something
};
```

Why this code doesn't work? In my head this is more logical than the classical prototypal inheritance.

Answer (score 9):

Your `var Foo = window.Foo = new Foo();` example is...odd. First you declare a function `Foo`, then you assign something to its prototype (I assume you meant to replace `Nannak` with `Foo` in your second line), and then you overwrite the reference to the function by assigning to it.

Standard Javascript prototypical inheritance looks like this:

```
// Create a constructor `Foo`
function Foo() {
}

// Give the prototype for `Foo` objects a function bound to the
// property `bar`
Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
}

// Only do this bit if you're doing this within a function and you want
// to make `Foo` available as a property of `window` (e.g., effectively
// a global variable. If this code is already at global scope, there's
// no need to do this.
window.Foo = Foo;
```

Here's how you'd use `Foo`:

```
// Create a `Foo` and use its `bar`
var f = new Foo();
f.bar();
```

A couple of other notes:

- Never use `new function() { ... }` unless you really, really know what you're doing. It creates an object initialized by the function, it does not create a new function. There's almost never any need for the similar (but *totally* different) `new Function(...)`, either, again except for some advanced edge cases.
- The function bound to `bar` in my example above is anonymous (the property it's bound to has a name, but the function does not). I'm not a fan of anonymous functions, but I didn't want to clutter the example above. [More here.](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html)
- If you use `var` at global scope (it wasn't clear from your question whether you were), it creates a property on the `window` object. You'd only need to do `var Foo = window.Foo = ...` if you're within a function and want to *both* create a propety of `window` *and* create a local variable called `Foo`. (Which maybe you meant to do! :-) )
- The `Foo.prototype = { .. };` way of assigning prototypical properties works, but it's not generally a good idea (again, unless you're pretty up-to-speed on this stuff). When you do that, you're *completely replacing* the prototype object used when you call the function via `new`, whereas if you just add properties to it (`Foo.prototype.bar = ...`), you're just augmenting the prototype, not replacing it. Replacing the prototype is perfectly valid, but there are some non-obvious things that can happen if you're unwary. :-)

Comment: Now I am wondering: what are those “advanced edge cases”? Are there [legitimate uses of the Function constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026089/legitimate-uses-of-the-function-constructor)

Comment: @Marcel: LOL! And the answer is: Of course there are. But you have to know what you're dealing with, and the OP is clearly a newbie (as we are were once), so...

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `new` operator on the function expression, that causes a newly created object to be assigned to `window.Foo`.

That new object is *not a function*, therefore it doesn't have a `prototype` property and it cannot be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

"doesn't work" is vague, but I think the root cause is `new function() {` (`new` doesn't belong here)

You probably want:

```
var Foo = window.Foo = function() {
};
Foo.prototype = {
  bar: 'baz'
};

alert(new Foo().bar); // baz
```