# what's the relationship between function and Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

as known in javascript, a function defined as

```
function somefunc(){
 }
```

is an instance of its constructor `Function`. But `Function` itself is a function either which implies the `Function` is an instance of `Function`. Is that what they are? Or there is some other relations between them.

Comment: Have a look at the ECMAScript specification, for example, [13.1   Creating Function Objects](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_13.2), maybe it helps.

Comment: There is no relationship between the constructor of the JavaScript function and the JavaScript function itself because the constructor of the JavaScript function isn't written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what they are.  `Function` is an instance of `Function`, as are all functions, including constructor functions.  This is completely expected and defined by the language specification.  All functions also inherit from `Object`, so the following statements are all true:

```
new Function() instanceof Function
(function () {}) instanceof Function
new Function() instanceof Object
(function () {}) instanceof Object
```

Functions can be created using function statements, expressions or the `Function` constructor.  See [Function constructor vs function statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799295/function-constructor-vs-function-statement).