# javascript function vs new Function

Tags: javascript

According to this benchmark
http://jsperf.com/function-vs-function
created functions run about 1000 times faster. Can you comment this?

Comment: Flawed micro benchmark is flawed. Aside from that, you're mainly testing for the performance of `console.log` here anyways :)

Comment: You are quite right!!!!!

Comment: On my computer it runs within +/- 3 percent, alternating. A few times I've obtained the exact same times for both scenarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You are calling `f1` but not `f2`. I.e. your second test is doing nothing but looking up a reference.
2. All the work is actually done as setup for the test.

I think what you want is actually this: http://jsperf.com/function-vs-function/2
**Update:** On second thought, you might not want this. But nevertheless, your second test is doing nothing. You are missing the `()` after `f2` ;)

So besides `new Function` being way slower, it is also harder to maintain the body of the function ;)

Answer (score 3):

with the `new Function`-syntax, for every function the JS-compiler has to be started to "eval" the function body string - this is slow and should be avoided when possible:

> Each time […] the Function constructor
>   is called on a string representing
>   source code, the script engine must
>   start the machinery that converts the
>   source code to executable code. This
>   is usually expensive for performance –
>   easily a hundred times more expensive
>   than a simple function call, for
>   example. (Mark ‘Tarquin’ Wilton-Jones)

if you had used the search on StackOverflow, you would have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3026089/288773) wich give very good and detailed information about that.

**EDIT:** like Martin said in one of the comments below, *sometimes* the `new Function`-constructor is a great thing. to list some examples:

- [John Resigs Micro-Templating Engine](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)
- [This piece of code from another Question an SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026089/legitimate-uses-of-the-function-constructor/3026622#3026622)
- to be continued...

but: in 99% of the cases where you *could* use `new Function`, it's a bad idea - wich means: to simply define any function that has to be like it is and doesn't have some kind of "dynamic bahavior", you should always use the "normal" function-syntax to speed up your code and avoid the `eval`-like functionality of `new Function`.

Comment: but new Function runs even faster! Do you also see what I see?

Comment: when i run you tests, i get "10,841,858 / fastest" for `function(){}` and "75,310 / 99% slower" for `new Function` - don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: Using ´new Function´ is not bad practice - it is an awesome tool, to be used when it is needed - people using it when it is not needed, that is bad practice. Saying that using ´new Function´ is bad practice is like saying "driving a car is bad practice", because some people run other people over while driving. That said, new Function is slower than a regular function and will always be, end of story.

Comment: @Martin: i deleted that sentence for being "too generally" - but i think we agree, that in "most cases", by wich i mean "for defining just a simple function that could be done exactly the same using `function(){}`-syntax", the `new Function`-syntax _is_ a bad idea. i agree with you that in _special cases_ it's a really great possibility.

Comment: @oezi: we agree absolutely :)

Comment: @Dan my firebug what deactivated while running your benchmark, i don't think it affects the results this way. is's a fact tha `new Function` is slower than normal function-syntax, if it#s now for you, tehres an eror in the benchmark. || @Martin: i edited my post trying to give some examples for "good" use of `new Function` - maybe you have any more suggestions.

Comment: @Dan maybe you shoudl take a look at Felix Klings benchmark here: http://jsperf.com/function-vs-function/2 - this seems to be more clearly than yours to show wich possibility performs faster.

Comment: If I create a `new Function` dynamically once, and call that function a million times, wouldn't the function itself run just as fast as a "hardcoded" function? Only eval'ing the string to executable code should be slow, but not the code itself (you should obviously not interpret the same string in a loop everytime).