# Legitimate uses of the Array constructor

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

I liked this question - [Legitimate uses of the Function constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026089/legitimate-uses-of-the-function-constructor) - so I wanted to create a similar question regarding the `Array` constructor.

Of course, the array literal notation is the correct way to create arrays. This would mean that the `new Array` notation should not be used. And "case closed".

However, there is one specificity of the `new Array` form. If a natural number is passed in, an empty array is created and its `length` property is set to that number.

So

```
arr = new Array( 7 );
```

is equivalent to

```
arr = [];
arr.length = 7;
```

This can be considered a feature. I was wondering if this "feature" has real-world uses. I recently stumbled upon one such (simple) use:

```
new Array( n + 1 ).join( '*' ) // returns string containing n stars

// e.g.
new Array( 3 ).join( '*' ) // returns '**'
new Array( 6 ).join( '*' ) // returns '*****'
```

This is cool, but was hoping for some more advanced uses. (Something that would make the `new Array` notation a legitimate tool in JavaScript programs.)

---

**Update:** I've noticed that the jQuery library uses the `new Array( len )` notation in one instance - it's inside the `when` function (search for `"when:"`):

```
when: function( firstParam ) {
    var args = sliceDeferred.call( arguments, 0 ),
        i = 0,
        length = args.length,
        pValues = new Array( length ),
        count = length,
        pCount = length,
        // etc.
```

They use it to initialize the `pValues` local variable, which is used in a local function further down in the code:

```
function progressFunc( i ) {
    return function( value ) {
        pValues[ i ] = arguments.length > 1 ?
                sliceDeferred.call( arguments, 0 ) : value;
        deferred.notifyWith( promise, pValues );
    };
}
```

I would love to know if changing the assignment to just

```
pValues = [],
```

would break the program... (Is `new Array( length )` required for `notifyWith` to work properly?)

Comment: FWIW, ECMA Harmony has [`String#repeat`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:string.prototype.repeat) which diminishes the usefulness of `new Array` somewhat.

Answer (score 3):

How about as an alternate way to shallow clone an Array?

```
var arr = [1,2,3];

var arr2 = Array.apply( null, arr );

arr === arr2; // false;

arr.length === arr2.length; // true
```

Yes, I'm reaching here because you'd just use `.slice()`, but then I really don't see using `Array` as illegitimate in the first place, as long as you know what you're doing.

---

Getting off topic, but one way to make a common function that utilizes `Array` or `slice`. Requires `bind`. <s>Too lazy right now to update for older browsers.</s>

http://jsfiddle.net/fdgBU/1/

```
var slicer,
    apply = Function.prototype.apply;

if( apply.bind ) {
    try {
        (slicer = apply.bind( Array, null ))({length:0});
    } catch( e ) {
        slicer = apply.bind([].slice);
    }
} else {
   slicer = function( coll ) {
        if( !coll || coll.length !== +coll.length ) return;
        var res = [], i = 0, len = coll.length >>> 0;
        for( ; i < len; ++i ) {
            res[i] = coll[i];
        }
        return res;
    };
}
```

---

```
var arr_like = {'0':true,'1':true,'2':true,length:3},
    arr = slicer( arr_like );

console.log( arr ); // [true, true, true]

console.log( arr.length === arr_like.length); // true
```

Comment: Or `Array.apply( null, arrayLike )` to convert array-like objects (like node-lists, or jQuery objects) to arrays. I tend to use `[].slice.call( arrayLike )` for this, but the first method seems "more proper"... **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/W8DjF/

Comment: I think the OP is talking about the Array constructor as in `new Array(n)`, not just the Array object.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Yes, I just did some testing in IE6 to make sure it worked that far back. It does, but only on the same objects that `.slice()` works on, in other words Arrays and Arguments. No other type of Array-like objects. Thought maybe there was a shot that it would work.

Comment: @jfriend00: But they're equivalent calls.

Comment: The main thing in my experience with

Comment: @Pointy: The suspense is killing me!

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Oh wait, I just tried it in Chrome, and it doesn't work. Where were you testing?

Comment: Oh crap sorry about that  @RightSaidFred - I got interrupted. Anyway the issue is that when you're using a server-side template language (php, jsp, whatever), and you code a `new Array(${foo})` where "foo" is *usually* a list of numbers, but sometimes it's just one number, then things don't work so well :-)  I just like being in the habit of using the bracket notation; it's less typing anyway.

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah, there are certainly situations where it wouldn't be wise to use it, and I do generally use `[]`. I'd just not be too quick to relegate it to a position of illegitimate.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Yep, Firefox works, but Chrome gives me an IE reminiscent `Uncaught TypeError: Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type`.

Comment: @RightSaidFred I use Firefox. It also works in Opera and IE9. I don't have Safari on my laptop. Could it be that this is a Chrome-specific issue?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: [Here's the issue](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=917).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: FWIW, you seem to [get a slight edge](http://jsperf.com/array-vs-slice) in Firefox with `Array.apply`

Comment: @RightSaidFred I suspected that the performance difference is because `[].slice` creates an empty array just to get the reference to `slice`, but even if `Array.prototype.slice` is used, and even if its cached, it's still slower `Array.apply`: http://jsperf.com/array-vs-slice/2

Comment: Oh, and yes I just tested Safari, and it works, so it's V8 specific.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: FYI, the [Chrome issue](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=917) is now [fixed](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/detail?r=9709).

Comment: @RightSaidFred Yay `:)` Btw, I'll get back to this thread later today. I have some updates to make to my original question...

Comment: "*How about as an alternate way to shallow clone an Array?*" - no. Try your code with `arr = [2]` to see it fail. You're right: `slice` is just simpler, and almost nobody knows what they're doing :-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this counts, but one case where you'd use the constructor is if you need to be sure you have clean, unmodified Array constructor. You can create an "iframe sandbox"

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var Safe = frames[frames.length - 1];
```

And then create arrays like this...

```
var things = new Safe.Array('x', 'y', 'z');
```

...knowing that your arrays will not have any foreign stuff in the prototype put there by other scripts.

That's not making use of that single-parameter-as-array-length feature, though. The only thing that's probably really good for is setting up huge arrays to benchmark stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much anything you can come up with a homebrewn map function (native `.map` doesn't iterate and `jQuery.map` is just full bugs)

Creating ranges:

```
//1-20

map( Array( 20 ), function( v,i ){
return i+1;
});
//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]


//-50 - 0

map( Array( 51 ), function( v,i ){
return i-50;
});

//[-50, -49, -48, -47, -46, -45, -44, -43, -42, -41, -40, -39, -38, -37, -36, -35, -34, -33, -32, -31, -30, -29, -28, -27, -26, -25, -24, -23, -22, -21, -20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0]
```

In general, instead of doing:

```
var a = [],
    l = 10;

    while ( l-- ) {
        a.unshift( 
            (function(l){
            return function() {
                alert( l );
            };
            })( l )
        );
    }
```

You can do this:

```
var a = map( Array( 10 ), function ( v, i ) {
    return function(){
        alert( i );
    };
});
```

Note that this only applies to `jQuery.map` or shimmed `.map`, native `.map` doesn't iterate the array.

If you're not using jQuery( which flattens the result :( ) you can create
three dimensional arrays like this:

```
var xyz = map(Array(10), function (v, i) {
    return map(Array(10), function (v, j) {
        return map(Array(10), function (v, k) {
            return i * 100 + j * 10 + k;
        });
    });
});

xyz[0][0][0] // 0

xyz[9][9][9] // 999

xyz[4][4][4] // 444

xyz[3][5][8] // 358
```

Of which the equivalent of for loops is pretty horrific :P

Quick implementation of a map function for completeness:

```
function map( elems, callback ){
var i, length = elems.length, ret = [];
    for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        value = callback( elems[ i ], i );
        ret[ ret.length ] = value;  
    }
return ret;
}
```

Comment: You can create your 3 dimensional Array with jQuery `$.map` if you just wrap each Array returned in another Array. It flattens the outer, but not the inner.

Comment: @RightSaidFred, is that a bug or a feature :D

Comment: Great question. :) The real bug is that it flattens in the first place, which just doesn't make sense for a `map` function. Alas, [it won't be fixed](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6183). It's an internal function that they felt comfortable with exposing in the public API irrespective of its unusual behavior.

Comment: @Raynos, not so fast. [].map doesn't work as explained later in the question :P `$.map( new Array(10), Number )
[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]` vs `new Array(10).map( Number )
[]`

Comment: @Esailija at least promote a homebrew `map` function

Comment: @Raynos, I am using homebrew function in my last example :P I might as well change them all since I have to use homebrew map function