# Recovering built-in methods that have been overwritten

Tags: javascript, browser, theory

Let's say that our script is included in a web-page, and a prior script (that already executed) did this:

```
String.prototype.split = function () {
    return 'U MAD BRO?';
};
```

So, the `split` string method has been overwritten.

We would like to use this method, so we need to recover it somehow. Of course, we could just define our own implementation of this method and use that instead. However, for the sake of this question, let's just say that we really wanted to recover the browser's implementation of that method.

So, the browser has an implementation of the `split` method (in native code, I believe), and this implementation is assigned to `String.prototype.split` whenever a new web-page is loaded.

We want that implementation! We want it back in `String.prototype.split`.

Now, I already came up with one solution - it's a hack, and it appears to be working, but it may have flaws, I would have to test a bit... So, in the meantime, can you come up with a solution to this problem?

Comment: @ЖΞЖ Using an iframe, as posted by Raynos. The inspiration for this question was [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8453585/425275) to one of my past questions...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
var _window = iframe.contentWindow;
String.prototype.split = _window.String.prototype.split;
document.documentElement.removeChild(iframe);
```

Use iframes to recover methods from host objects.

Note there are traps with this method.

```
"foo".split("") instanceof Array // false
"foo".split("") instanceof _window.Array // true
```

The best way to fix this is to not use `instanceof`, ever.

Also note that `var _split = String.prototype.split` as a `<script>` tag before the naughty script or *not including* the naughty script is obvouisly a far better solution.

Comment: Can you think of any flaws with this method? Could there be issues, like with the `instanceof` operator, since the methods "belong" to foreign constructors... ?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas flaws are implementation specific. `.split` returns an Array that's either an instance of `window.Array` or `_window.Array`

Comment: According to [this test](http://jsfiddle.net/gCCKf/), the resulting array is an instance of `window.Array` in Firefox and Safari, but an instance of `_window.Array` in the other browsers.

Comment: I guess there's no way to access the original versions of functions, namely `Object.defineProperty` and/or `Object.freeze`, in a potentially hostile environment where *anything* writeable might have been patched—including `document.createElement`, `window.open`, etc?