# How to restore an overridden function's original state in Javascript

Tags: javascript

let's say that you have a script that needs to run on a page that overrides javascript's `JSON.stringify`, how would you ensure that your code would use the original stringify not the overridden one?

Comment: Run your code before the other code has a chance to modify it? I seriously doubt you can find what was there before a variable (or a function, as in this case) gets overwritten...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580431/recovering-built-in-methods-that-have-been-overwritten
Seems you can create an iframe, and access its (brand-new, unmodified) contents. Also, your question is a duplicate of this one, and should be closed as such.

Comment: I'm building an app that has a bookmarklet, and noticed a website overrides stringify and causes an error. since it's a bookmarklet running it before the page is not an option

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I would opt for one of the *other* answers, here is a solution for the case when:

1. The page *cannot* be altered and thus;
2. Code *cannot* be run before the code that overwrites JSON.stringify and thus;
3. Code *cannot* save the original function-object (to restore it or use it explicitly later).

Here is then a hack:

1. Create an IFRAME element.
2. Access the `contentWindow` property of the IFRAME element; this should then contain the original (or "a new untouched") JSON object and thus the original JSON.stringify function.

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSypG/)

Comment: It was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating a library, make it a requirement that `JSON.stringify` should conform to the standard behavior.

There's nothing wrong with placing strict requirements on your code, and it is in fact a good idea. You just need to be certain to document the requirements.

Obviously if the original is permanently overridden, you can't use it. Placing the burden on the end user is a better solution.

If this is not for a library, but rather for a personal project, you should simply refuse to load any 3rd party code that does something as foolish as replacing a conforming method with a non-conforming one.

Comment: This is the elegant solution ("do not have this problem in the first place"). The ugly solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580431/recovering-built-in-methods-that-have-been-overwritten

Comment: Unfortunately the elegant solution is not always an option in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Make a backup of `JSON.stringify` before it's overwritten. If you can't make a backup of it, use [a shiv](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).