# Javascript converting a set into an array returns an empty array caused by a website

Tags: javascript, overriding

I came across a site named "[FurAffinity](https://www.furaffinity.net/)", and was toying around with userscripts. I discovered something strange with while being on that site that this JS code does not work (it happens on both on a userscript, and on the devtool's console):

```
Array.from(new Set([1,2,2,3]))
// returns "[]" instead of "(3) [1, 2, 3]"
```

Entering that code on the default page of the browser (appears when you create a new tab) will do the latter result as expected, but not while on FurAffinity.

Is there any explanation of why this occurs? If so, is there any way to re-override it to do the default array method? Also if so, is there any way to prevent websites from overriding any JS methods of the userscript? I already know you can convert a set into an array using a spread syntax (`[...ExampleSet]`) as a workaround, however I'm concerned about other commonly-used JS methods and functions like `String.<Insert method name here>` and `/<regex>/.test(String)` could get altered and not behave as it supposed to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore an overridden function's original state in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522618/how-to-restore-an-overridden-functions-original-state-in-javascript)

Comment: Umm, no, because I'm working on a userscript that runs on any website. This means that it is possible that one or more functions and methods could get overridden and not behave as expected. Worse is if I made a complex userscript and every one of the default functions and methods are altered, and have to manually "restore" each and every one of them. Is there a piece of code or some kind of instructions to make the userscript ignore changes by the website?

Comment: @AAsomb113 websites that alter the default behavior of JS are the problem.

Comment: The link @DjaouadNM shows creating an iFrame, the iFrame will have all default functions from JS land, not sure how is that not what you asked for?.

Comment: Nevermind. I discovered why, and it was a silly mistake. There is HTML code that already has the iframe, and trying it out on userscript causes it to look for an iframe that doesn't exist.