# Get back default implementation of window.Map

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I'm writing Javascript code in a Salesforce.com Visualforce page. Unfortunately, Salesforce overrides `window.Map` with an incompatible map implementation. Is there some way to get back what *used* to be stored at `window.Map`?

Comment: Did you try asking this in [salesforce.se]? Had the same issue. `:D`

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered in a [generic context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8580576/1048479) by @Raynos, but you can use an iFrame to recover the original `Map`:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
document.body.appendChild(iframe)
var _window = iframe.contentWindow
VanillaMap = _window.Map
```