# How to protect your JS library from being effected by another library modifying the global Object prototype

Tags: javascript, web

I'm working on a JavaScript library that gets included in my customers application via a script tag.

Another library they want to include is making changes to the `Object.prototype`  by adding methods `setObject` and `getObject` as well as `Object.prototype.properties`. This interferes with the execution of our code.

I would like to know if it's possible to protect our library for any manipulation of global prototypes, even beyond this specific example.

Comment: You could use some code like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580431/recovering-built-in-methods-that-have-been-overwritten

Comment: It's indefensible to modify `Object` in this way.  I'd push back on that customer, strongly.  Even if you manage to solve this problem, that other poorly written library is going to create other problems for you.