# JavaScript - Detect Native Code [Monkey Patch]

Tags: javascript

There's a lot of posts about "Detecting Native Code" Which most of them use a simple string check `WebSocket.toString()` to see if the native function was modified, However this wasn't efficient and very easily bypassable.

```js
window.WebSocket = new Proxy(window.WebSocket, {
  get(target, property){
        if(property == 'toString'){
            return () => 'function WebSocket() { [native code] }'
        }
      return target[property]
     }
})
```

or

```js
window.WebSocket.toString = () => {return 'function WebSocket() { [native code] }'}
```

However, with enough thinking.. I've come up with a potentional way to patch it. I'll leave the answer below. Let me know what you think about the solution, and is there any flaws you see?

Comment: Question: why? just why?

Comment: To prevent cheaters from hooking native functions to get access to functions they cant normally access.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work in all browsers ... I bet you only tested in Chrome - so, your code allows you to access something inaccessible? or the opposite?

Comment: Yes. It's not a complete project, its a suggested solution, otherwise I wouldn't post it here. I am looking for improvement suggestions or potentional flaws/issues like you mentioned. My code detects if the person attempted to modify native function and block their connection.

Comment: Fair enough ... Firefox doesn't like it ... not sure what happens, but it's not good

Comment: @RovenA Could [restoring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8580576/5648954) the original WebSocket be enough for what you want to do? Rather than detecting if it's been modified.

Comment: @NickParsons Yes, is there any way to restore original without running into trap functions?

Answer (score -1):

```js
delete Symbol.prototype.toString;

/* Get unmodified toString property */
function TruePrototype(Prototype) {
  var _ = Prototype.toString;
  var __ = Prototype.toString?.toString;
  var ___ = Prototype.toString();
  var ____ = Prototype.toString.toString();
  while (Symbol(__).description !== "function toString() { [native code] }") {
    _ = _.toString;
    __ = __.toString;
  }

  return (__.apply(Prototype) === `function ${Prototype.name}() { [native code] }`);
}

TruePrototype(WebSocket) // True

window.WebSocket = new Proxy(window.WebSocket, {
  get(target, property){
        if(property == 'toString'){
            return () => 'function WebSocket() { [native code] }'
        }
      return target[property]
     }
})

TruePrototype(WebSocket) // False
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).