# How slow is John Resig's JavaScript Templating Engine?

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js

`with` is so [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1463937/946789) that it is forbidden in ES5 strict mode.

*Function constructor* is [very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3026089/946789).

Yet, 
[John Resig's micro templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) is advertised as **light**, uses **both** mentioned bad features of Javascript. (same with another *light* templating - [underscore's](http://underscorejs.org/#template), which is a fork of it)

Now a question:
 **How seriously should i be concerned about performance impact of using those template engines ?**

Should i sacrifice their flexibility and simplicity for speed gains that other engines (like Mustache, or XTemplates) might provide ?

Comment: Are you building a Facebook-sized operation? Or a small website that no one will use? 'impact' is relative.

Comment: well, Facebook's JS is not _that_ huge, complex or particularly fast. My concerns are directed for HTML apps on embedded devices. (So they are supposed to run for very long time (few hours without page reload), compared with facebook's 5 minutes / 10 transitions) and also they must render without *any* noticeable delays...

Comment: Are you going to run it on coffepots with 1 MHz CPU or wrap every span in a template? Otherwise it is hardly so important. A function call costs far below 1ms.

Comment: John Resig doesn’t query the DOM, he just glances at it and gets all the elements he was expecting. Clearly it works differently for the rest of us. http://benalman.com/news/2009/12/john-resig-javascripts-chuck-norris/

Comment: How about if you make a slow/test, just create a template, run it like 10000 times, take the time, repeat with whatever other template engine you know and thats it.
The code is extremelly simple,
https://gist.github.com/topliceanu/1537847

it must be fast.